# Tool to check non-SSL calls?

Tags: https, tools

Is there a tool that will scan all elements on a webpage and report which item is making a non-SSL call? My webapp keeps showing the mixed use icon and everything I can see is good. :/

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the source code for links that start with http://? This includes images, CSS, scripts, flash, etc.

Comment: Yes, of course.  :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13107/firefox-reports-https-page-to-contain-non-secure-elements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  You launch the application from your local machine and can see each and every HTTP request being made to load up your page.  That will tell you for sure all of the elements that may be making non-SSL requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the page in Firefox 4 then you get a page info dialog. On the media tab you can see all the images that are included. You can see if they begin with https. Otherwise Firebug, the Firefox plugin, lets you see which scripts, css files you're using, even if they are loaded via Javascript.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I tried Firebug but found nothing, so I'm trying to find something more obvious.